# Hadoop -copyFromLocal cannot find input file

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -copyFromLocal input.csv input.csv
copyFromLocal: `input.csv': No such file or directory
```

Can anyone tell me the exact reason why I am getting this kind of error? I gave all permissions to the `input.csv` file and I even changed the owner to hdfs. I am new to Hadoop and Hbase.

Comment: Are you running this command in a directory that contains input.csv?

Comment: Yes . even i tried by giving full qualied path of that input.csv file.. still same result.                                                   sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/amiverma/input.csv /hbase/input

Answer (score 4):

In this case you are trying to read the file as the hdfs user, which may not have permission to view this file. To test, do this:

```
sudo -u hdfs cat input.csv
```

If you get permission denied, you either need to change the permissions of this file so the hdfs user can read it (or if it already has read permissions, move the file to a directory that the hdfs user can read), or use a different user that has permission to access the local and the remote directories/files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that user `hdfs` has read permission to all the parent directories of `input.csv` along the path.

Answer (score 0):

**syntax: hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal completelocalfilesystempath hdfspath**

**Example:** Let input.csv be in localpath /usr/examples and my hdfs path where it needs to be copied is /usr/input so the command will be

**hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /usr/examples/input.csv /usr/input/**

Comment: Thanx vinay for your quick response yeah even I tried with complete local file system path , still output is same .   And the command looks like as                                                    sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/amiverma/input.csv /hbase/input/

Comment: Hi MadhusudhanaReddy actually the command sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/amiverma/input.csv /hbase/input/ is showing Exception of permissions so i tried using hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /home,amiverma/input.csv /hbase/input/  it worked

Answer (score 0):

To copy files you can run it like this:

```
cat input.csv | sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -put - input.csv
```